# Efficiently counting team pull requests across 200+ repos in Github

Tags: github, methods, github-api, pull-request

I am trying to report on the number of total and daily number of pull requests that are done by my team on github repos that the team owns. The only caveat, however, is that the team owns more than 200 repos. Because of this, I am hesitent against the brute force method of solving this issue which is query listing all the repos owned by the team and query list and count the pull requests done within each repo (which may also have a chance of being paginated due to the high frequency of pull requests). Is there any function or method that would be more efficient than this brute force process? Ideally, I was wonderring if there was a command that can accumulatedly list or count all the pull requests done by my team within all our repos?

TLDR: Is there a method or better way to count both the total number of pull requests and the daily number of pull requests done by my team across all of our repos?

I have tried looking in numerous places but have not been able to find anything specific for github teams. I have found methods involving listing the pull requests for each user but that's basically it. I was hoping to find a method or a better algorithm to find the total number of pull requests done by my team across all of our repos.